# Parallelized version of code takes longer to run

Tags: r, loops, machine-learning, parallel-processing

I have the following code that is running fine:

```
# first code: works fine

# Step 1 : Create Data for Example:
library(dplyr)
library(ranger)

original_data = rbind( data_1 = data.frame( class = 1, height = rnorm(10000, 180,10), weight = rnorm(10000, 90,10), salary = rnorm(10000,50000,10000)),  data_2 = data.frame(class = 0, height = rnorm(100, 160,10), weight = rnorm(100, 100,10), salary = rnorm(100,40000,10000)) )

original_data$class = as.factor(original_data$class)
original_data$id = 1:nrow(original_data)

test_set=  rbind(original_data[ sample( which( original_data$class == "0" ) , replace = FALSE , 30 ) , ], original_data[ sample( which( original_data$class == "1" ) , replace = FALSE, 2000 ) , ])

train_set = anti_join(original_data, test_set)
```

The actual code starts here:

Step 2:

```
# Step 2: Create "Balanced" Random Subsets:

results <- list()
for (i in 1:100)
   
{
   iteration_i = i
   
    sample_i =  rbind(train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "0" ) , replace = TRUE , 50 ) , ], train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "1" ) , replace = TRUE, 60 ) , ])
   
    results_tmp = data.frame(iteration_i, sample_i)
    results_tmp$iteration_i = as.factor(results_tmp$iteration_i)
   results[[i]] <- results_tmp
   
}

results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

X<-split(results_df, results_df$iteration)

 invisible(lapply(seq_along(results),
       function(i,x) {assign(paste0("train_set_",i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
       x=results))
```

Step 3:

```
# Step 3: Train Models on Each Subset:
wd = getwd()
results_1 <- list()

for (i in 1:100){
     
    model_i <- ranger(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]], probability = TRUE)
    saveRDS(model_i, paste0("wd", paste("model_", i, ".RDS")))
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i   
}
```

Step 4:

```
# Step 4: Combine All Models and Use Combined Model to Make Predictions on the Test Set:
results_2 <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
predict_i <- data.frame(predict(results_1[[i]], data = test_set)$predictions)


predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
 results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
   
}

final_predictions = aggregate(.~ id, do.call(rbind, results_2), mean)
```

I am planning on running this code on a dataset of about 200 million rows. I would like to speed this code up (Step 2, Step 3, Step 4) - I tried looking at different ways to do this, and came across "parallelization". Apparently, this can be done using libraries such as "future"/"foreach". Here was my attempt to parallelize the above code:

```
# second code: takes a long time to run 
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores())
foreach(i = 1:100, .packages = 'ranger') %dopar% {
        # Step 2: Create "Balanced" Random Subsets:

results <- list()
for (i in 1:100)
   
{
   iteration_i = i
   
    sample_i =  rbind(train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "0" ) , replace = TRUE , 50 ) , ], train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "1" ) , replace = TRUE, 60 ) , ])
   
    results_tmp = data.frame(iteration_i, sample_i)
    results_tmp$iteration_i = as.factor(results_tmp$iteration_i)
   results[[i]] <- results_tmp
   
}

results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

X<-split(results_df, results_df$iteration)

 invisible(lapply(seq_along(results),
       function(i,x) {assign(paste0("train_set_",i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
       x=results))

# Step 3: Train Models on Each Subset:
wd = getwd()
results_1 <- list()

for (i in 1:100){
     
    model_i <- ranger(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]], probability = TRUE)
    saveRDS(model_i, paste0("wd", paste("model_", i, ".RDS")))
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i   
}

# Step 4: Combine All Models and Use Combined Model to Make Predictions on the Test Set:
results_2 <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
predict_i <- data.frame(predict(results_1[[i]], data = test_set)$predictions)


predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
 results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
   
}

final_predictions = aggregate(.~ id, do.call(rbind, results_2), mean)
    
}

stopImplicitCluster()
```

For some reason, it seems that contrary to what I would have thought - parallelization is making this code take a lot longer to run.

**My Question:** Does anyone know if there are any other ways to speed up this code? I have a feeling I have not correctly understood the concepts behind parallelization - can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: Only a part of the code can be actually parallelized. There is an overhead because one need to setup each worker. For loops can usually not be parallelized, because one iteration step might depend on the previous one. Use `foreach(i = 1:10) %do%` instead and `pbmclapply` instead of `lapply`.

Comment: Indeed, to make better use of parallelisation it'd be advised to find which parts of your code can be vectorised, vectorise them, then parallelise. Alongside the setup costs of running in parallel, you're also reducing the throughput in the sequential parts of your code.

Comment: @ danloo: thank you for your reply! I will look into these functions!

Comment: You could use `system.time()` to measure time needed to run step2+3+4 : on my computer this is around 10s - no need for parallelization because overhead will add more seconds. Do you have a bigger dataset that makes these steps much longer?

Comment: Did you notice that `model_i` used in step 4 is always the same, ie last value defined for `i=100` in step 3?

Comment: @ Waldi: thank you for your reply! Yes, I am planning on running this code on a dataset of about 200 million rows!

Comment: @ Waldi: Thank you for your observation! I think you are correct! In step 4, I should be referencing the "list of models" ( results_1[[i]]) from step 3, correct? I will make these changes right now!

Comment: @ Waldi : I made these changes! Please let me know if you have any other questions! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Parallel processing comes with the overhead of launching parallel tasks and putting together the results : [it isn't always faster](https://heather.cs.ucdavis.edu/rparbookch2.pdf).

Before thinking about parallelizing, you could first identify the most time consuming parts of your code.

`profvis` package is a way of [profiling code](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/218221837-Profiling-R-code-with-the-RStudio-IDE):

```
library(profvis)

profvis({
# Step 2: Create "Balanced" Random Subsets:

results <- list()
for (i in 1:100)
  
{
  iteration_i = i
  
  sample_i =  rbind(train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "0" ) , replace = TRUE , 50 ) , ], train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "1" ) , replace = TRUE, 60 ) , ])
  
  results_tmp = data.frame(iteration_i, sample_i)
  results_tmp$iteration_i = as.factor(results_tmp$iteration_i)
  results[[i]] <- results_tmp
  
}

results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)

X<-split(results_df, results_df$iteration)

invisible(lapply(seq_along(results),
                 function(i,x) {assign(paste0("train_set_",i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
                 x=results))

# Step 3: Train Models on Each Subset:
wd = getwd()
results_1 <- list()

for (i in 1:100){
  
  model_i <- ranger(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = X[[i]], probability = TRUE)
  saveRDS(model_i, paste0("wd", paste("model_", i, ".RDS")))
  results_1[[i]] <- model_i   
}

# Step 4: Combine All Models and Use Combined Model to Make Predictions on the Test Set:
results_2 <- list()
for (i in 1:100){
  predict_i <- data.frame(predict(results_1[[i]], data = test_set)$predictions)
  
  
  predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
  results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
  
}

final_predictions = aggregate(.~ id, do.call(rbind, results_2), mean)
})
```

According to `profvis`, the most time consuming step is `saveRDS`:
[image]

However, this only accounts for 1.3 seconds, whereas using `system.time()` instead of `profvis` shows that the code needs about 6 seconds to complete.

Reading [profvis FAQ](https://rstudio.github.io/profvis/faq.html#why-does-sys.sleep-not-show-up-in-profiler-data) explains that :

> Calls to external programs and libraries also may not show up in the profiling data. If you call functions from a package to fetch data from external sources, keep in mind that time spent in those functions may not show in the profiler.

Timing each step alone shows that step 4 takes around 3 seconds and isn't accounted for by `profvis`.

This leads to the function which is called there : `predict.ranger`

`?ranger::predict.ranger` shows that this function is multithreaded :

> num.threads : Number of threads. Default is number of CPUs available.

Meaning that the CPU is already using all it's processors most of the time, so that extra parallel processing won't help much, or might even be slower!

This can be seen on the task manager (x-axis = time, y-axis = CPU use from  0 to 100%):

- with `for` loop :
  [image]
- with `foreach` loop :
  [image]

You'll find hereafter the parallelized (or not) code used to compare performance. I put all loops together in one single loop.

Note that under Windows, you should use  `makeCluster` instead of `registerDoParallel` to [setup number of cores used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45823182/13513328).

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

cl <- makeCluster( detectCores()-1) 
registerDoParallel(cl)


# Step 2: Create "Balanced" Random Subsets:
  results <- list()
  results_1 <- list()
  results_2 <- list()
  wd = getwd()
  
# Measure performance  
  system.time({

  foreach (i = 1:1000,.packages='ranger') %dopar% # Parallel version
# for (i in 1:1000)                               # non parallel version
  {
    iteration_i = i
    
    sample_i =  rbind(train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "0" ) , replace = TRUE , 50 ) , ], train_set[ sample( which( train_set$class == "1" ) , replace = TRUE, 60 ) , ])
    
    results_tmp = data.frame(iteration_i, sample_i)
    results_tmp$iteration_i = as.factor(results_tmp$iteration_i)
    results[[i]] <- results_tmp
    
  
  # not necessary in loop
  # results_df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
  # X <- split(results_df, results_df$iteration)
  
  invisible(lapply(seq_along(results),
                  function(i,x) {assign(paste0("train_set_",i),x[[i]], envir=.GlobalEnv)},
                   x=results))
  
  # Step 3: Train Models on Each Subset:
 
    model_i <- ranger(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = results_tmp, probability = TRUE)
    saveRDS(model_i, paste0("wd", paste("model_", i, ".RDS")))
    results_1[[i]] <- model_i   
  
  
  # Step 4: Combine All Models and Use Combined Model to Make Predictions on the Test Set:
  
    predict_i <- data.frame(predict(model_i, data = test_set)$predictions)
    predict_i$id = 1:nrow(predict_i)
    results_2[[i]] <- predict_i
    list(i,model_i,predict_i)
  }
  })  
 
  final_predictions = aggregate(.~ id, do.call(rbind, results_2), mean)
  stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: @ waldi: thank you so much for your answer! I will have to spend some time learning about the information you kindly provided. Just a question - in these graphs: what do the x-axis and the y-axis represent? I am guessing that the y-axis somehow represents the computer resources being used? But I am not sure about the x-axis. Thank you so much!

Comment: The graphs represent CPU use from 0 to 100% on y axis, x-axis being time. The rise corresponds to beginning of calculation.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes:

1. When running on 2E8 rows, you may want to make sure not to keep everything in memory and use fast operations. The `data.table` package may be useful here due to its performance and in-memory replacements. Maybe you do not need to export all training sets into the Global environment in step 2; I do not see where you use that, and it will take up a lot of memory (memory usage may become a primary concern here).
2. Looking purely at performance, saving all the models as RDS objects is quite time consuming. Unless required later, skipping this step might speed things up quite a bit. If you have memory issues and need to spill to disk, you may consider saving the predicted output, perhaps with `data.table::fwrite` and subsequently read it in with `data.table::fread`.
3. For some reason, despite the `ranger` and `predict` functions using multiple threads, running these steps in parallel may still give some speed improvements, depending on the way you can parallelize. In a linux environment, `mclapply` forks the process and does not copy data to all the nodes, so YMMV using other parallelization options. A few good suggestions for alternative ways to schedule in parallel are already in other comments/replies.
4. Unless I overlooked it, it seems to me that you could sample your training set once and then split into multiple parallel sets, as I did not see where you would use multiple iterations that feed sequentially into each other.

Below is one example that probably could be optimized further, depending on the memory profile

```r
library(data.table)
library(parallel)
ncores <- floor(detectCores()/2)-1 # set no. of cores for parallel processing
trs <- setDT(train_set, keep.rownames = TRUE) # turn into data.table 
n <- 1e2 # number of sampling iterations
# sample once, then label as iterations
results <- trs[c(sample(which(trs$class==0), 50*n, replace = TRUE), 
    sample(which(trs$class==1), 60*n, replace = TRUE))]
results[, iteration:=NA_character_]
results[class==0, iteration := as.character(cut(1:(50*n), n, labels = 1:n))]
results[class==1, iteration := as.character(cut(1:(60*n), n, labels = 1:n))]
results[, iteration := factor(iteration, order(unique(as.numeric(iteration))))]

# Step 3: Train Models on Each Subset:
calc_model <- \(x) ranger(class ~  height + weight + salary, data = x, probability = TRUE)
predict_model <- \(x) data.table(predict(calc_model(x), data = test_set)$predictions)[, id:=.I]
# save time and memory not saving model as RDS file; potentially, the list of models could 
# be saved in one write operation, which could also be faster

# Step 4: Combine All Models and Use Combined Model to Make Predictions on the Test Set:
# for some reason, despite predict using multiple threads, I still profit 
# from parallelization here; skipping generation of X to save memory
results_2 <- mclapply(results[, unique(iteration)], 
    \(x){predict_model(results[iteration == x])}, mc.cores=ncores)
final_predictions <- rbindlist(results_2)[, lapply(.SD, mean), .SDcols=c("0", "1"), by="id"]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ user12728748: thank you so much for your answer! The reason why I was saving each model as an RDS file was to save my progress in case the computer crashes ... this way I could save my work.

Comment: You have used a lot of functions that I am not familiar with - I will have to study these functions to better understand them and get back to you!

Comment: Overall, what do you think of the code I have written? I would appreciate your comments and feedback - thank you so much!

Comment: @stats_noob,  loops are fine, the overall process seems to work for you, and there are certain things to consider when running parallel processes, e.g. available RAM and CPUs - esp. with large datasets where memory issues might become a bottleneck. Hence, it may help not to keep everything as objects that take memory (exporting the multiple iterations, saving the objects, saving the split list, ...), but whether this will give you a noticeable performance benefit (and if you need to take any precautions to save memory, buffer to disk, etc.) depends on how and on what hardware you run on.